# Laravel 6 routing without domain name

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have Laravel installed on a server, and I can navigate to its IP in a web browser to see my page.

I edited web.php inside Laravel's routes folder:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return view('test');
});
```

When I visit `http://[my server's IP]/test`, I get a 404.

I have a test.blade.php, which looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Test</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tested it with "/", and it works, but I need to make it work with "/test".

Should I just move onto something else other than Laravel? I've been having nothing but constant problems with it. It's hard to believe it's so widely used.

My result of `php artisan route:list`:

```
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | test     |      | Closure | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Is that Laravel server running on a different machine? If not, why not use `http://localhost`? How are you running your server, `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Or you can also restart your server. `ctrl + c` then `php artisan serve` again.

Comment: If it works with `http://[your server's IP]/index.php/test?name=myName` then you should enable `mod_rewrite` on web server.

Comment: @Tpojka, it does not work with that address.

Comment: Whether I'm using php artisan serve or not, it does not work with "/test".

Comment: `/index.php/test` doesn't work at all?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Any other suggestions? Laravel seems rather broken.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cache after you changed your route?

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Also try

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: Yes, same result. 404.

Comment: Have you cleared the route cache? php artisan route:cache

Comment: I have before, but now it is giving me a "LogicException" error immediately after. "Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure."

Comment: Yeah. I believe that to be normal behavior with Laravel when using a closure in the routes. Definitely not idea. It is a little extra work, but try and move this into a controller method.